# Is gap filler suitable for a 2-3" gap between soffit and wall?

Tags: roof, soffit

While cleaning out a bird's nest along the eaves, I noticed that there are sizable gaps between the soffit (such as it is) and the wall. The gap varies between 2-3 inches. The soffit (white board) seems to be in ok shape.

Would something like gap fill work here? Is there a better way to fill this gap? It's not a constant width, so I'm not sure what else would work. Or should I just bite the bullet and remove the white board and replace it with something wider?

While the last option is probably the best, I'd rather avoid it for a while if possible.

[image: gap between wall and soffit]

Comment: Maybe it’s for a soffit vent and you shouldn’t cover it. Do you have a soffit vent already? Do you need one?

Comment: In which case it should be screened. This is an open invitation to rodents, bees, bats, squirrels, possums, flying termites, birds.

Comment: I don't know that it was intended as a vent. There are portions that are blocked totally with a combination of 2x4s and scrap. It sounds like a screen is a good approach. Now I just need to figure out the best way to do it. Thanks